# Google Dialogflow Response Construction

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to send a payload from my service with a Basic Card and the payload I am sending looks like such with the following fulfillmentMessages:

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "simpleResponses": {
        "simpleResponses": [
          {
            "displayText": "A 13-inch laptop with advanced color, sound and streaming for an immersive viewing experience. Featuring Dell Cinema and next-generation InfinityEdge.",
            "ssml": "<speak>Here's the first item I found. XPS 13 on sale for $849.99. To navigate you can say Next, Previous, or First. You can also say 'More Details' or 'Text me the product link'.</speak>"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "basicCard": {
        "buttons": [
          {
            "openUriAction": {
              "uri": "https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/xps-13-9370-laptop/dycwi622h"
            },
            "title": "See on Dell.com"
          }
        ],
        "formattedText": "A 13-inch laptop with advanced color, sound and streaming for an immersive viewing experience. Featuring Dell Cinema and next-generation InfinityEdge.",
        "image": {
          "accessibilityText": "product image",
          "imageUri": "https://i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent//content/dam/global-site-design/product_images/dell_client_products/notebooks/xps_notebooks/13_9370/global_spi/rose_gold/notebook-xps-13-9370-best-of-500-rosegold-ng.psd?fmt=png-alpha"
        },
        "subtitle": "$849.99",
        "title": "XPS 13"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am running into issues with Actions On Google throwing errors with my payload defined this way:

```
MalformedResponse
Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response.
```

I am unsure what the issue is here, or why Actions on Google throws this exception when the Dialogflow tester shows our card as expected.

How do I correctly format my payload so that both Actions on Google and Dialogflow display as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Needed to assign the platform value to each message object as "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE".